# Phone number output

Tags: php

I would like to print raw phone number record (31999999) as 31-999-999 (PHP). I have never done that before. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Will the input always look like this? Will the output always look like this? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$phone = 31999999;

$formatted_phone = preg_replace("|\b(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})\b|", "$1-$2-$3", $phone);

echo $formatted_phone;
```

This is what I came up with, there might be simpler ways but this seem shortest. However, it will only accept an exact 8 digit number, nothing more nothing less. If you want a different pattern, you'll need to specify your input exactly.

Comment: This is cool because it will display the original number if the formatting didn't work. Should you maybe add `^` and `$` to the regex?

Comment: No, because the following will work on "This is a string blah blah 12345678 blah" (Also, replace with `preg_replace_all()` if you want several numbers in a single string, but be careful as it will have unexpected behavior with numbers longer than 8 digits)

Answer (score 2):

We can take advantage of PHP's weak type system, so it doesn't matter if the number is stored as a string or not:

```
$num = 112223333;
echo substr($num,0,2) . "-" . substr($num, 2, 3) . "-" . substr($num, 4, 4); // 11-222-2333
```

edit: As per Oli's comment below, while it's of interest that this code works whether $num is a string or an int, for the sake of clarity and to avoid bugs you should store $num as a string.

Comment: Well, hopefully the OP isn't storing phone numbers as anything other than a string.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: That's a good point - I mentioned it for completeness since the format wasn't indicated. I'll edit the answer accordingly though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate substrings in order to do this.  Luckily, PHP has a [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.